# Code compare login and password

Tags: java, jsf

I have written a simple code to test login and password ,(login and password are given by the user) and then I compare them by login and password stored in the database. but the problem is the function return bad result (it browse all the rows even it is true at the first row)
this is the code:

```
public String LoginPasswordCheck(Connection con) 
{ 
    HashMap<String,String> mapLoginPWD = new HashMap<String,String> ();
    String sqlLogin;
    String checkaccess="true";
    String log;
    String pwd; 
     sqlLogin="select login ,password from profil_user;";

    try{
   st=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sqlLogin);
   ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery();

   while(rs1.next())
    {
      log = rs1.getString("login");
      pwd=rs1.getString("password");
      mapLoginPWD.put(log, pwd);
   } 

Iterator iteratorkey = mapLoginPWD.keySet().iterator(); 
String myKey="";
String value="";

while(iteratorkey.hasNext())
{
 myKey = (String) iteratorkey.next();
 value= mapLoginPWD.get(myKey);
 //login and password given by the user
 if( !(this.login.equalsIgnoreCase(myKey)) && !(this.password.equalsIgnoreCase(value) )&& !(iteratorkey.hasNext()) )
  {
          checkaccess ="fail";
  }
else

             checkaccess ="success"; 
}

}
 catch (SQLException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }     
return checkaccess;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you load a map of logins and passwords for each request. You could just load the password for the given login and if that fails, the login does not exist.

Futhermore, i wonder if you really want to ignore case on passwords and logins.

The code you present fails because you do not exit the loop when you find the matching login/password.

You should really refactor the code and eliminit the need for maps and looping. As i said, just look for the login that the user presents in your database.

Comment: I want to relate each login with the equivalent password

Comment: @Rym ok, then the method name is misleading. I thought you want to check the password for one given login.

Comment: ah it's my mistake I have forgotten to change it

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

- The SQL query returns a resultset for all users. You could specify a WHERE clause that would restrict this to 0 or 1 rows, depending on whether the user exists or not.
- The code iterates through the results, and sets a flag. If the flag is set once, it can (and would be) reset on the next iteration. You should break out of the loop (so that once authentication is considered successful, it cannot be considered unsuccessful for the provided user ID and password). But if you were to fix the previous problem, then you don't need the loop in the first place.
- It is unnecessary to store the contents of the resultset in a map. This is redundant, for the map is rebuilt on every query and discarded after execution.